# Request using axios in Nuxt app does not return complete data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am making a request to my API I get the response without a certain field named `location` but making the same request in my postman returns the complete data. Below is my code:

The function that makes the request to the API and I `console.log` the result

```
getProperty() {
            this.$axios.get(`/place/${this.$route.params.id}`)
            .then(result => {
                const property = result.data
                this.property = property
                console.log(property);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            })
        },
```

below is the logged result and as we can see there is no field called location  which is populated with data from the browser

```
accessibility: Array(0)
amenities: (...)
createdAt: (...)
deactivated: (...)
description: (...)
featured: (...)
idealfor: (...)
img: (...)
owner: Object
phone: (...)
price: (...)
time: (...)
title: (...)
toilet: (...)
typeof: (...)
unavailabledate: (...)
updatedAt: (...)
__v: (...)
_id: (...)
```

when I make the same request to the postman below is the response with the location i want showing in the response

```
{
    "location": {
        "country": "Nigeria",
        "state": "Lagos",
        "city": "Lekki",
        "zip": "100295",
        "street": "23 palm beach"
    },
    "time": {
        "alwaysopen": false,
        "open": "10:00",
        "close": "20:00"
    },
    "price": {
        "amount": 25000,
        "currency": "NGN"
    },
    "phone": {
        "number": "08125580085",
        "code": "+234"
    },
    "idealfor": [
        "production"
    ],
    "amenities": [
        "electricity",
        "a/c"
    ],
    "accessibility": [],
    "unavailabledate": [],
    "deactivated": false,
    "img": true,
    "featured": false,
    "_id": "60dc4da4531bb067c4d85886",
    "title": "Palm Beach",
    "description": "Palm Beach is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
    "typeof": "beach",
    "toilet": 2,
    "owner": {
        "profilePhoto": {
            "location": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14Gi6-VULzc-VUxVOxXQRA0wgpdze2Jv7XJ2uGcLU5Q=s96-c"
        },
        "isEmailConfirmed": true,
        "isVerified": false,
        "isAdmin": false,
        "isActive": true,
        "hasSpecialPrevilege": false,
        "savedplaces": [],
        "_id": "60db368751d83400151932dc",
        "email": "opeyemiodedeyi@gmail.com",
        "fullname": "opeyemi odedeyi",
        "createdAt": "2021-06-29T15:04:39.383Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-06-30T00:32:43.368Z",
        "__v": 6
    },
    "createdAt": "2021-06-30T10:55:32.522Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-06-30T10:56:03.730Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: This seems like a backend issue. Your API server is determining whether to send `location`. What's the backend code for that route?

Comment: Are you sure you get the whole payload here?

Comment: I was able to solve it, I just deleted the collections from MongoDB atlas and recreated it, thankfully I am still in development mode. It works properly now, after creating some properties @tony19